# Stream Analytics jobs receive no input

Tags: azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I downloaded and deployed the [Remote Monitoring Azure IoT Suite](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring) project. The only change I made to the deployment template was to deploy a free version of IoT Hub instead of S2. I am using the [Azure IoT SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks) to send messages to the IoT Hub. Monitoring on Azure Portal shows me that messages are arriving.

But when I look at the three Azure Stream Analytics jobs, none of them are receiving any inputs. It's like IoT Hub isn't letting any of the ASAs know that there is data to process. The permissions are unchanged. IoT Hub has a policy with all permissions and all the ADAs are using that policy. I created a new ADA with the same policy and I don't get any data in that one either.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: What do you see in the operations log of stream analytics job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was a glitch in Azure. I came back and everything was magically working. Sigh...